# Loop over 10 lists by list numbers

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append images in 10 different lists based on their image label.

For example :

```
list_0, list_1, list_2, list_3,....list_9 # 10 different lists

if np.argmax(p, axis=1) == 0:
    list_0.append(image)
elif np.argmax(p, axis=1) == 1:
    list_1.append(image)
elif np.argmax(p, axis=1) == 2:
    list_2.append(image)
.
.
.
elif np.argmax(p, axis=1) == 9:
    list_9.append(image)
```

How can I do it in one line? Ultimately I dump the classifier's prediction with its data using pickle.dump. So for dumping, I have to again call the list 10 times. I am looking for a better coding style to optimize my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be easier if you collect all the lists into one list, then we can just use np.argmax(p, axis=1) to index them:

```
all_lists = [list_0, ..., list_9]

index = np.argmax(p, axis=1)
if 0 <= index <= 9:
    all_lists[index].append(image)
```